# 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis', trying to explode column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to handle the following error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.
My dataset looks like

```
first_column   second_column   ... fifth_column                ... eleventh_column ...    Age
example 1       first ex           ['avers','aaa','hello']              41241              12
example 2       second ex           []                                  431                32
another         third ex           ['AA','B','C','aaa','hello']         21                 32
example 1       example           ['avers','aaa','hello']              41241              12
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
first_column   second_column   ... fifth_column  ... eleventh_column ...    Age
    example 1       first ex           avers              41241              12
    example 1       first ex           aaa                41241              12
    example 1       first ex           hello              41241              12
    example 2       second ex            nan                431              32
    another         third ex           AA                    21              32
    another         third ex           B                     21              32
    another         third ex           C                     21              32

    another         third ex           aaa                   21              32
    another         third ex           hello                 21              32

    example 1       example           avers               41241              12
    example 1       example           aaa                 41241              12
    example 1       example           hello               41241              12
```

For my understanding, I should apply `explode`:

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
df1=df.set_index('first_column').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
df1.fifth_column
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe help you?

Comment: Please provide your data in pandas dataframe format, as a dictionary, or at least remove the elipses so that we can read it with `pd.read_clipboard()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are absolutely sure, it's usually not advisable to use an index that has duplicate values (as in your `first_column`) because it can be unsupported for certain operations.

Since it looks like you are trying to reset the index to default integer values anyway and just using `set_index()` to remove the 'leftover' index values of `df`, I would suggest the following:

`df1 = df.apply(pd.Series.explode).set_index('first_column').reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to check without data in pandas dataframe format, but it looks like you're applying explode to the whole dataframe, where you should be applying it just to `fifth_column`. You need to pass a column name to explode as an argument. `df.explode('fifth_column')` should probably appear somewhere in your code.